# jenkins bash script - remove directory path from find command results

Tags: bash, jenkins, find

I need to search in my dist directory for minified .js and .css files within jenkins.

I have a bash script with a find cmd, like this:

```
for path in $(/usr/bin/find dist/renew-online -maxdepth 1 -name "*.js" -or -name "*.css" -type f); do
# URL of the JavaScript file on the web server
url=$linkTarget/$path
echo "url=$linkTarget/$path"
```

Where linkTarget is: http://uat.xxxx.com/renew-online.

I want to attach the minified files form dist/renew-online to the linkTarget,
for example:

http://uat.xxxx.com/renew-online/main-es2015.cf7da54187dc97781fff.js

BUT I keeping getting: http://uat.xxxx.com/renew-online/dist/renew-online/main-es2015.cf7da54187dc97781fff.js

I've tried with -maxdepth 0 also but can't get the correct url - newbie at scripts!

Hopefully one of you guys can help, thanks your time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is more a bash question than a jenkins one and you have multiple ways to do it.

If all your files are in a single path, and actually you are forcing with the depth, you can use a cut

```sh
for path in $(/usr/bin/find dist/renew-online -maxdepth 1 -name "*.js" -or -name "*.css" -type f | cut -d'/' -f2); do
```

In the other hand the here https://serverfault.com/questions/354403/remove-path-from-find-command-output by the usage of `-printf '%f\n'`

Please note as well that the usage of find in a for `loop` is fragile and it is recommended to use a `while` https://github.com/koalaman/shellcheck/wiki/SC2044

**EDIT**
the field used in cut depends on the folders you have in your find syntax. The most accurate way is the one in the serverfault link above

Comment: thanks for the reply/answer - had to change f2 to f3 to get it to work - thanks you

Answer (score 2):

This can be achieved by using 'find' command only:

```
/usr/bin/find dist/renew-online -maxdepth 1 \( -name "*.js" -o -name "*.css" \) -type f -printf "$linkTarget/%f\n"
```

It is also recommended to isolate 'or' statements inside round brackets.

Comment: thanks for the reply this works also - not sure which one is the best - so accepted the first answer